Variation in tone
Assuming these are grammatically accurate by themselves, what different mood do they give?
Reus judicandus or Reus ad judicandum or Reus judicandus est.

This appears to be a follow-up question to this one.

Is Est needed?     (comments must be at least 15 characters in length.)

If you have further clarification of your question, you can edit the body of the question instead of posting a comment.
